# Issues passing array's and calculating the average C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been stuck on this for over a day now. This code is supposed to find the maximum and minimum number of numbers within a text file then output the average of those numbers.  Everything is working fine except for the average.  Its not calculating at all.  I know the issue is that I'm not correctly using my arrays within my find_average function but, for the life of me, I just can't wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong.  Please help.

```
//  Student:        Tyler Brady
//  Assignment:     5
//  File:           assing5.cpp
//  Input:          Keyboard

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // I/O
#include <iomanip> // For setw()
using namespace std;
ofstream outputfile("output.txt");
const int MAX_FILE_NAME = 35;  // Maximum file name length
const int MAX_NUMBER_SCORES = 40;  // Maximum number of values in array
void open_input(ifstream& input, char name[]);                       // Get file name, Open file
void read_values(ifstream& input, double v[], int size, int& used);  // Read values from file
void find_max_min(const double v[], int n, double& max, double& min);// Find max/min in array
void output(const char name[], const double v[], int n,
    double max, double min, double average, ostream &out = cout);            // Print Results

double find_average(const double v[], int n);

int main()
// Parameters: None
// Returns:    Zero
// Calls:      open_input(), read_values(), find_max_min(), output()     
{
    char     again;                        // Does user want to go through loop again?
    char     file_name[MAX_FILE_NAME + 1]; // Name of file to be processed
    ifstream input_numbers;                // Input file of doubles
    double   scores[MAX_NUMBER_SCORES];    // Array to hold scores processed
    double   max, min;                     // Maximum and minimum numbers from file
    int      num_scores;                   // Number of scores in file

    double average;

    cout << "This program can find the largest and smallest numbers in a file\n"
        << "of at most " << MAX_NUMBER_SCORES << " floating-point values.\n" << endl;
    system("pause"); // Hold message on screen until key is pressed

    do
    {
        open_input(input_numbers, file_name);    // Get file name & open file
        read_values(input_numbers, scores,
            MAX_NUMBER_SCORES, num_scores);       // Read values
        input_numbers.close();                   // Close file
        if (num_scores > 0)
        {
            find_max_min(scores, num_scores, max, min); // Find max & min values in array
            average = find_average(scores, num_scores);
            output(file_name, scores, num_scores, max, min, average); // Print results on screen
            output(file_name, scores, num_scores, max, min, average, outputfile); // and outputfile
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\n\aNo data in file: " << file_name << endl;
        }

        cout << "\nDo you want to process another file (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> again;
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');  // Remove Enter key from keyboard buffer
    } while (again == 'y' || again == 'Y');

    cout << "\nEnd of Program!" << endl;
    outputfile << "\n\nThanks for using MaxMin!\f";
    outputfile.close();
    return 0;
}  // End of main()

void open_input(ifstream& input, char name[]) //Open file
                                              // Parameters: Variables for input file reference nad input file name
                                              // Returns:    None
                                              // Calls:      None
{
    int count = 0;             // Count number of tries
    do // Continue until we get a valid file name and can open file
    {
        count++;
        if (count != 1)  // Issue error message if we are trying again.
        {
            cout << "\n\aInvalid file name or file does not exist. Please try again."
                << endl;
        }
        cout << "\nEnter the input file name (maximum of " << MAX_FILE_NAME
            << " characters please)\n:> ";
        cin.get(name, MAX_FILE_NAME + 1);// Gets at most MAX_FILE_NAME characters
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');           // Remove Enter key from keyboard buffer
        input.clear();                   // Clear all error flags, if any, from prev try
        input.open(name, ios_base::in); // Open to read only if file exists
    } while (input.fail());            // If can't open file, try again
} // End of open_input()

void read_values(ifstream& input, double v[], int size, int& used) // Read values
                                                                   // Parameters: Variables for file reference, variable for array reference,
                                                                   //             value for array size and variable for number of values in array
                                                                   // Returns:    None
                                                                   // Calls:      None
{
    double value;        // Value from file
    int count = 0;       // Count number of values in file

    while (count < size && input >> value) // Continue as long as there is 
                                           // room in the array and we can read
    {
        v[count] = value;                   // a number from file.
        count++;
    }

    used = count;
} // End of read_values()

double find_average(const double v[], int n)
{
    double value;
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (count >> value)
    {
        sum += value;
        count++;
    }
    return sum / count;
}

void find_max_min(const double v[], int n, double& max, double& min) // Find max & min values
                                                                     // Parameters: Variables for array reference, value for number of values 
                                                                     //             and variables for max and min values
                                                                     // Returns:    None
                                                                     // Calls:      None
{
    int i;   // Array index and loop counter

    max = min = v[0];

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) // Start with 1 since max & min initialized to v[0]
    {
        if (v[i] > max) max = v[i];
        if (v[i] < min) min = v[i];
    }
} // End of find_max_min()

void output(const char name[], const double v[], int n,
    double max, double min, double average, ostream& out)
    // Parameters: File name, array reference, number of values and max & min values
    // Returns:    None
    // Calls:      None
{
    int i;  // Array index and loop counter
    out.setf(ios::fixed);
    out.setf(ios::showpoint);
    out.precision(1);
    out << "\n\nInput File Name:         " << name << endl;
    out << "\nFile Contents:" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; )
    {
        out << setw(8) << v[i];
        if (++i % 5 == 0) out << "\n"; // Print only 5 values per line
    }
    if (i % 5 != 0) out << "\n";      // Newline if last line is short
    out << "\nLargest  Number in File:        " << setw(8) << max << endl;
    out << "Smallest Number in File:        " << setw(8) << min << endl;
    out << "Average of Numbers:        " << setw(8) << average << endl;
} // End of output()
```

Comment: like all your other functions you need to traverse the array with a for loop.  Why are you not doing that in `find_average()`?

Comment: Step 1. Learn how to debug code (and maybe how to isolate issues and create [mcve]). Also you should *really* prefer `std::vector` or `std::array` over raw arrays

Answer (score 0):

It is the while loop in the find_average function that is not ok. In the count >> value statement, the variable value is not initialized, so you it's value can be anything (trash), and the shift operator can't be used with double.

You can try this:

```
while (count < n)
{
    sum += v[count];
    count++;
}
return sum / count;
```

Or use a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sum += v[i];
}
return sum / n;
```

Comment: _It is the while loop in the find_average function that is not ok._ Can you explain, why isn't it OK, and how does your solution solve said problem?

Comment: Thanks Rofellos. Worked perfect!